# How to access this.props.children functions in React

Tags: reactjs

Here is the component hierarchy I have.

```
<Parent>
    <Child1>
        <Child2>
        </Child2>
    </Child1>
<Parent>
```

In **Child2** component, there is a function called **handlePatch()**.
I need to call it from **Parent** component but not sure how to do it.
What is the best approach for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could pass on a `ref` of the `Child` component to the `Parent` as props and access that to call the function like

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
       super();
       this.child = null;
    }
    render() {
        return (
             <Parent childRef={this.child}>
                <Child ref={(ref) => this.child = ref}/>
             <Parent>
        )
    }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
    myfunc = () => {
        //call child function
        this.props.childRef.handlePatch();
    }
}
```

However you can try to avoid it by restructuring your code a little better and directly calling the function in `Child` from the container of `Parent` component.

Comment: Thanks, Shubham. I've update the description for more complicated senario. can you let me know how?

Comment: It doesn't matter how nested the cmponents are, you could use the same approach

Comment: Hi Shubham. sorry, is this the best approach? any work around via props, etc?

Comment: This is the simplest approach and the one which was suggested on one of the issues I was going through on github